# What is a Eligible Schedule Instance in Privileged Identity Management?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-rbac

I am working with the Az and the Graph Powershell Module, getting information about role assignments in Entra ID and Azure Resource Manager. I found that there is two commands each I can use to query information about what user has which eligible role assignments.

For Entra ID:

```
Get-MgBetaRoleManagementDirectoryRoleEligibilitySchedule
Get-MgBetaRoleManagementDirectoryRoleEligibilityScheduleInstance
```

For Azure Resource Manager:

```
Get-AzRoleEligibilitySchedule
Get-AzRoleEligibilityScheduleInstance
```

So what is the difference between a schedule and a schedule instance? Which one represents the role assignment I see in the Azure Portal (UI)? Is one deprecated and preferred over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portal shows you *role eligibility schedule instances*.

If you create a *role eligibility schedule* with a start time in the future:

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{subscriptionId}}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilityScheduleRequests/{{$randomUUID}}?api-version=2020-10-01
{
    "properties": {
        "principalId": "721e3492-6665-4731-8884-e161fb727951",
        "requestType": "AdminAssign",
        "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/9033657c-5138-4300-a892-4b6dead220c2/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c",
        "scheduleInfo": {
            "expiration": {
                "type": "AfterDuration",
                "duration": "P180d"
            },
            "startDateTime": "2023-12-04T11:15:00Z"
        }
    }
}
```

..and then check portal, it's empty.

[image]

If you query *role eligibility schedules*, you see the `Granted` schedule:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{subscriptionId}}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilitySchedules?api-version=2020-10-01
{
    "value": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "roleEligibilityScheduleRequestId": "/subscriptions/9033657c-5138-4300-a892-4b6dead220c2/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilityScheduleRequests/25213440-0863-436d-abde-c37c7b05001a",
                "scope": "/subscriptions/9033657c-5138-4300-a892-4b6dead220c2",
                "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/9033657c-5138-4300-a892-4b6dead220c2/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c",
                "principalId": "721e3492-6665-4731-8884-e161fb727951",
                "principalType": "Group",
                "status": "Granted",
                "startDateTime": "2023-12-04T11:15:00Z",
                "endDateTime": "2024-12-03T11:15:00Z",
                "memberType": "Direct",
                "createdOn": "2023-12-04T11:02:12.167Z",
                "updatedOn": "2023-12-04T11:02:12.167Z",
                "expandedProperties": {
                    "principal": {
                        "id": "721e3492-6665-4731-8884-e161fb727951",
                        "displayName": "CSG-RBAC-Test",
                        "type": "Group"
                    },
                    "roleDefinition": {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/9033657c-5138-4300-a892-4b6dead220c2/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c",
                        "displayName": "Contributor",
                        "type": "BuiltInRole"
                    },
                    "scope": {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/9033657c-5138-4300-a892-4b6dead220c2",
                        "displayName": "sub-sbx-sbx",
                        "type": "subscription"
                    }
                }
            },
            "name": "25213440-0863-436d-abde-c37c7b05001a",
            "id": "/subscriptions/9033657c-5138-4300-a892-4b6dead220c2/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilitySchedules/25213440-0863-436d-abde-c37c7b05001a",
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilitySchedules"
        }
    ]
}
```

..but if you query *role eligibility schedule instances* (again **before** the start time), the response is empty:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{subscriptionId}}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilityScheduleInstances?api-version=2020-10-01
{
    "value": []
}
```

Checking portal again **after** the start time (plus a few mins for something to happen behind the scenes in PIM) you see the *role eligibility schedule instance*:

[image]

Same in the *role eligibility schedule instances* API:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{subscriptionId}}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilityScheduleInstances?api-version=2020-10-01
{
    "value": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "roleEligibilityScheduleId": "/subscriptions/9033657c-5138-4300-a892-4b6dead220c2/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilitySchedules/25213440-0863-436d-abde-c37c7b05001a",
                "scope": "/subscriptions/9033657c-5138-4300-a892-4b6dead220c2",
                "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/9033657c-5138-4300-a892-4b6dead220c2/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c",
                "principalId": "721e3492-6665-4731-8884-e161fb727951",
                "principalType": "Group",
                "status": "Provisioned",
                "startDateTime": "2023-12-04T11:15:16.823Z",
                "endDateTime": "2024-12-03T11:15:16.773Z",
                "memberType": "Direct",
                "createdOn": "2023-12-04T11:15:16.823Z",
                "expandedProperties": {
                    "principal": {
                        "id": "721e3492-6665-4731-8884-e161fb727951",
                        "displayName": "CSG-RBAC-Test",
                        "type": "Group"
                    },
                    "roleDefinition": {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/9033657c-5138-4300-a892-4b6dead220c2/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c",
                        "displayName": "Contributor",
                        "type": "BuiltInRole"
                    },
                    "scope": {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/9033657c-5138-4300-a892-4b6dead220c2",
                        "displayName": "sub-sbx-sbx",
                        "type": "subscription"
                    }
                }
            },
            "name": "da93a041-529e-45ac-a095-ee314398ca5d",
            "id": "/subscriptions/9033657c-5138-4300-a892-4b6dead220c2/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilityScheduleInstances/da93a041-529e-45ac-a095-ee314398ca5d",
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilityScheduleInstances"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm unaware of any way to see future-dated schedules in the portal.

Interestingly, if you go back to the *role eligibility schedules* after the start time passes, the `status`, `startDateTime`, `createdOn` and `updatedOn` fields have all been touched:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{subscriptionId}}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilitySchedules?api-version=2020-10-01
{
    "value": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "roleEligibilityScheduleRequestId": "/subscriptions/9033657c-5138-4300-a892-4b6dead220c2/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilityScheduleRequests/25213440-0863-436d-abde-c37c7b05001a",
                "scope": "/subscriptions/9033657c-5138-4300-a892-4b6dead220c2",
                "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/9033657c-5138-4300-a892-4b6dead220c2/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c",
                "principalId": "721e3492-6665-4731-8884-e161fb727951",
                "principalType": "Group",
                "status": "Provisioned",
                "startDateTime": "2023-12-04T11:15:16.823Z",
                "endDateTime": "2024-12-03T11:15:16.773Z",
                "memberType": "Direct",
                "createdOn": "2023-12-04T11:15:16.823Z",
                "updatedOn": "2023-12-04T11:15:16.823Z",
                "expandedProperties": {
                    "principal": {
                        "id": "721e3492-6665-4731-8884-e161fb727951",
                        "displayName": "CSG-RBAC-Test",
                        "type": "Group"
                    },
                    "roleDefinition": {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/9033657c-5138-4300-a892-4b6dead220c2/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c",
                        "displayName": "Contributor",
                        "type": "BuiltInRole"
                    },
                    "scope": {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/9033657c-5138-4300-a892-4b6dead220c2",
                        "displayName": "sub-sbx-sbx",
                        "type": "subscription"
                    }
                }
            },
            "name": "25213440-0863-436d-abde-c37c7b05001a",
            "id": "/subscriptions/9033657c-5138-4300-a892-4b6dead220c2/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilitySchedules/25213440-0863-436d-abde-c37c7b05001a",
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilitySchedules"
        }
    ]
}
```

Only words I've ever found to describe the difference are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/privileged-role-eligibility-rest-sample#list-eligible-assignments

HTH

Comment: Just now saw your answer for some reason, it helped for sure!

Answer (score -1):

> What is a Eligible Schedule Instance in Privileged Identity Management?

The **Get-MgBetaRoleManagementDirectoryRoleEligibilitySchedule/Get-AzRoleEligibilitySchedule**-:  The command retrieves the eligibility schedule for a resource scope in `Azure Active Directory`

Using this cmdlet, administrators can gather information about when certain roles can be assigned to users, helping them plan and manage role assignments efficiently within their `Azure AD environment`.

The **Get-MgBetaRoleManagementDirectoryRoleEligibilityScheduleInstance/Get-AzRoleEligibilityScheduleInstance** : The command retrieves the specified role eligibility schedule instance in `Azure Active Directory`

It's important to note that the **Beta** in `Get-MgBetaRoleManagementDirectoryRoleEligibilitySchedule` and `Get-MgBetaRoleManagementDirectoryRoleEligibilityScheduleInstance` indicates that these are in the `Microsoft Graph Beta API`, which means they are not yet generally available and could be subject to changes. On the Azure side, `Get-AzRoleEligibilitySchedule` and `Get-AzRoleEligibilityScheduleInstance` are part of the stable `Az module` for `Azure PowerShell.`

Reference :
[Get-AzRoleEligibilitySchedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azroleeligibilityschedule?view=azps-11.0.0) &  [Get-AzRoleEligibilityScheduleInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azroleeligibilityscheduleinstance?view=azps-11.0.0)

[Get-MgBetaRoleManagementDirectoryRoleEligibilitySchedule](https://alyaconsulting.ch/Solutions/Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Identity.Governance/Get-MgBetaRoleManagementDirectoryRoleEligibilitySchedule)

Comment: Bro really just explained the words "schedule" and "instance" with the words themselves

Comment: Check this link about Get-Mgbeta command: 
 https://alyaconsulting.ch/Solutions/Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Identity.Governance/Get-MgBetaRoleManagementDirectoryRoleEligibilitySchedule

Comment: Are you looking for differences in commands or guidance on how to use the commands?

Comment: I am trying to understand why there is two different commands (`Get-*Schedule` and `Get-*ScheduleInstance`) which seemingly do the same. The Microsoft document does not explain much. What is the difference between `Schedule` and `Schedule Instance`? And which one is the more "correct" one for the task at hand (find eligible role assignments).

Comment: The **Get-AzRoleEligibilitySchedule** retrieves information about the schedule itself, while **Get-AzRoleEligibilityScheduleInstance** retrieves information about the instances of the schedule.
To find eligible role assignments, you should use the **Get-AzRoleEligibilityScheduleInstance** command. This command retrieves the eligibility schedule instance for a role, which will tell you whether a particular user or group is eligible to be assigned that role. Here is the [result](https://i.imgur.com/7kmSafC.png) of the **Get-AzRoleEligibilityScheduleInstance** command.

Comment: I hope this helps your query!